# How to find anti-correlated subsequences in correlated time series?

Tags: time-series, correlation, random-variable, pearson-r

Say I have two time series $X_t$ and $Y_t$ (with $ 1 \leq t \leq N$), which have a high positive Pearson correlation. Say I also have reason to believe there are subsequences $X_{tj}, Y_{tj}$ (where, for each $j = 0, 1, \ldots, J$, the variable $t$ is restricted to $n_j$ contiguous values), such that the time series $X_{tj}, Y_{tj}$ are negatively correlated.

How do I find such subsequences?

Also, is there a name for this kind of problem and the techniques used to solve it?

Comment: By your "subsequences $X_{tj},Y_{tj}$", are you referring to lagged serieses at some lag $X_{(t+l)-t},Y_{(t+l)-t}$?

Comment: I don't think so -- I mean just that there are $J$ sets  of contiguous values of $t$, i.e. $J$ local environments within $1,2,\ldots, N$, for which the correlation becomes negative. So if we picked out these $J$ subsequences and computed the correlation on them, the correlation would be negative. Also, I don't understand your expression for lag. Doesn't it just simplify to $X_l, Y_l$, where presumably $l$ is a constant?